# escape sequences for executing a command with system() in c++, under linux

Tags: c++, linux, system

I want to execute a command using `system()`. The command needs a file name as a parameter. Something like this:

```
void f(string filename){
  strnig cmd = "path/to/my/command " + filename; 
  system(cmd.c_str());
  ... 
}
```

My question is what escape sequences could I use so that the string received in filename will be considered just the name of the file and nothing more. For example, if `filename = "aname;rm *"`, I don't want my command to be executed on `"aname"` and then `"rm *"` to be considered a new command and to delete everything from my current directory.

Also, I wish that my filename to be able to contain special characters like: `'`,`"` or space, without affecting the command execution.

How do I do this in c++?

Thank you!

Comment: You might consider using something like `execv()` instead of `system()`. It's a more complex to use (but that complexity can be hidden in a function) and you don't get wildcard expansion, but you also won't get the behaviors of the shell that you don't want.  If you don't want or need wildcards, I think `execv()` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

man system:

> system()  executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command

so use the escape sequences your shell honors.

Comment: My question is how do I apply the escape sequences in c++? Is there any other solution to do this, than just parsing the filename and then checking each character to see if it is a special character and then prefix it with a "\"?

Comment: Ah, I see. I am afraid you are out of luck, and the manual solution is the only way. That is, if you insist on `system`, use of which is highly discouraged, partially for this very reason. A `fork/exec` idiom is much preferred.